# Several JButtons store values in one array?

Tags: java

I'm making a lottery program and what I want is to have several JButtons on-screen that when clicked on store the numbers in an array. Here's my code so far, I'm a beginner so I have no idea what to do next, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
    b1 = new JButton();
    b1.setLocation (5, 5);
    b1.setSize (50, 50);
    //b1.setText ("1");
    b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("jedan.png"));
    c.add(b1);

    b2 = new JButton();
    b2.setLocation (60, 5);
    b2.setSize (50, 50);
    b2.setText ("2");
    c.add(b2);        

    b3 = new JButton();
    b3.setLocation (115, 5);
    b3.setSize (50, 50);
    b3.setText ("3");
    c.add(b3);
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Maybe have a look at [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing for you to do is to create an `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> lotteryNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you need to perform the action of adding numbers to your array whenever a button is pressed. This is where you need to create an `ActionListener`.

I recommend creating an inner class that implements the `ActionListener` interface so that you can reuse this class with each button.

```
// This code should go within the same class that you declare your ArrayList
private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener {

    // This is the method that will be called when a button is clicked.
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            lotteryNumbers.add(Integer.parseInt(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to instantiate an instance of this class and add it as an `ActionListener` to all your buttons.

```
ActionListener buttonClickListener = new ButtonClickListener();

b1.addActionListener(buttonActionListener);
b2.addActionListener(buttonActionListener);
b3.addActionListener(buttonActionListener);
```

***Note***: For this to work I am assuming that the text on each button corresponds to the lottery number that you want to add to the array. I am also assuming that the button text contains ONLY numeric characters that can be converted to an integer.

Comment: Well I was thinking to use images instead of numbers on buttons, but it really doesn't matter. Anyway thank you for help!